# How can I print a pixel-perfect margin-less page from Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, printing

I have been trying to print a set of graphs from Excel onto A4, but with no margins. To find the perfect column length to row height ratio, I've used the dimensions of standard A-class paper which is approximately \sqrt{2}.

Using continued fractions, I've found a very good approximation to be 1393/985, and so I set the pixels as such.
I set 55 columns at 25 pixels width plus one at 18 (55 * 25 + 18 = 1393), as well as 39 rows of 25 pixel height and one of 10 (39 * 25 + 10) = 985.

Printing on A4 in landscape, this produces unexpected results... there is a lot of space still left to fill on the print preview. I have set the margins all to 0 on custom margins and with "no scaling" set.

Why doesn't this work?

Comment: Does your printer support borderless-printing? If so, make sure it is enabled in its settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't print to the absolute edge of the page, because nearly all printers have a 'no-print' zone on all four sides of the page, which varies with the model of printer. Telling the printer to print in the no-print area can have unexpected results.

Comment: Some photo printers can print to the edge for standard photo and sheet sizes, but the printer needs to have that feature and you typically need to select that mode in the driver at print time.